# Apache2 - How to disable a module by vhost?

Tags: module, apache2, vhosts

I wish to disable a module only in one vhost ?

How I can set it in my vhost declaration, if that's possible ?

Comment: I think you cannot "unload" a module per vhost, but maybe you can disable it by configuration. So, which module do you want to disable?

Comment: That's this module cband => http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/documentation/
That's bug in one of my website, so I wish to keep it active, but disable in one vhost only :/

Answer (score 0):

The Apache modules are loaded server-wide, so you cannot disable them by vhost. But depending on the module, you can configure it to do nothing by putting the right directives inside the vhost config. For example, this can be used for `mod_security` and `mod_rewrite`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName example.com

  # mod_security
  <IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </IfModule>

  # mod_rewrite
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine off
  </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```